# Create a text file on server which can be modifiable by all client users in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to create a log file on server which tracks the details of all client login.. 
for that i took web service path

```
string p2 = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "ServerLog.txt";
public void log(string logData)
    {
        lock (logLock)
        {
            fs = new FileStream(p2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" " + logData + "\n");
            m_streamWriter.Flush();
            m_streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have written the above code in WebService and by creating a service object am accessing it.. And am able to modify it . but once my system created that file and one other user try to modify it ,then an error shows as:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

The second user can continue the logging on server if the file from server is removed.. but anyone except the second can do the logging.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead of yours.

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(" " + logData + "\n");
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to close the `streamWriter` here since it is inside a `using` statement. And i will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the stream and also likely use "append" mode. [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) is the method that will take care of your needs.

```
var filename = p2;
using(var streamWriter = File.AppendText(filename))
{
   streamWriter.WriteLine(" " + logData + "\n");
}
```

Side note: there are many existing logging solutions - please consider using them instead of inventing your own...